# PHP MySQL While Loop Multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, while-loop

Morning peps!

I'm having some troubles getting my query to work properly. I've created a search field which pulls rows from multiple tables (invoices, customers). For example, when ever I'm searching for invoice "2014-003", which is the only invoice with that nr., then I'm getting a list of all of my customers and then the same invoice nr. all the way down..

My code:

```
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM invoices, customers
    WHERE invoice.customer_id = customers.id AND
    (customers.name LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR
    (invoices.invoice_nr LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR
    (invoices.email LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR
    (customers.email LIKE '%" . $search . "%')");
```

I suck at english, so I think it's better for me to maybe write an example below:

I'll search for the invoice nr. "2014-003" which is unique, and what I get is this:

```
    Peter - 2014-003
    Christian - 2014-003
    Adam - 2014-003
    Frederick - 2014-003
    Peter - 2014-003
```

and it should return:

```
    Adam - 2014-003
```

because Adam is the only one who has an invoice with the following invoice nr.

I hope you'll understand what I want to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
$results = $db->query("
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      invoices, 
      customers
    WHERE 
      invoice.customer_id = customers.id AND
      ((customers.name LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR
       (invoices.invoice_nr LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR
       (invoices.email LIKE '%" . $search . "%') OR
       (customers.email LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
      )");
```

Your ORs are not grouped properly, hence the AND validates, but is later relaxed because it gets a hit on one of the ORs - whereas your OR's are really referring to a group of possible conditions (but the original join needs to stay in place)

Comment: Show some love by accepting the answer when you can :)

Comment: I surely will, but I'll have to wait another 3 mins. before I can accept :)